# Using javascript class based style as Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm pretty much new to the Vue Eco-System, buh I'd like to achieve something as below:

```
**VisitListTemplateFile.vue**
<template>...</template>
<script>
    import  VisitListView from '../../views/VisitListView'
    import '../../assets/vendor/datatables/app.datatables';
    import Body from '../partials/Body';
    export default new VisitListView("VisitListView", Body);
</script>

<style scoped>
    @import "../../assets/vendor/datatables/datatables.min.css";
</style>

**VisitListViewFile.js**
import {BaseView} from '../../core/BaseView';

export default class VisitListView extends BaseView {

    constructor(name, ...components) {
        super(name, ...components);
    }

    mounted() {
      console.log("TEST");
    }
}
```

It works kind of, but I realize that the callback functions e.g **mounted** isn't called, although there is a workaround to make it work. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

**----UPDATE----**

I did this and it works, so my question is, does this pose any problem?

```
BaseView.js
export class BaseView {
    constructor(name, ...components) {
        this.name = name;
        this.components = {};

        components.forEach(comp => {
            this.components[comp.name] = comp;
        });

        return {
            components: this.components,
            mounted: this.mounted
        }
    }

    mounted(){
        super.mounted();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you defined BaseView?

Comment: ```export class BaseView {
    constructor(name, ...components) {
        this.name = name;
        this.components = {};
        components.forEach(comp => {
            this.components[comp.name] = comp;
        });
    }
}```